# Is there coordinates $u,v$ such that $e^{-x^2-4y^2}dx\wedge dy = du\wedge dv$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there coordinates $u,v$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $e^{-x^2-4y^2}dx\wedge dy = du\wedge dv$?

Comment: Hint - try the analogous question for $\mathbb R^1$  without the $y$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

You have one choice as $ u = \int e^{-x^2}dx , v = \int e^{-4y^2}dy$.

You cannot integrate this explicitly.

Comment: One probably should put in limits; otherwise, it's not a specific function - the proverbial "+C" of cal 1.... e.g., $u = \int^x_0 e^{-x^2}\,dx$

Comment: Map $(x,y) \mapsto (\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt,\int_{0}^{y}e^{-4t^2}dt)$ is not surjective..
So it's not answer